# How to design a threshold function without using any comparison operator?

Tags: number-theory, functions

What are some methods to design a function that outputs $1$ if the input value $x$ is greater than a threshold $T$ and $0$ otherwise.

$f(x,T)=\begin{cases} 1,x\geq T\\
0, x<T \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x,T) = \left\lceil\frac{1}{2}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x-T}{|x-T|+1}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{T-x}{|x-T|+1}\right\rfloor + 1\right)\right\rceil$$

is a candidate, if you allow floor and ceiling operations. If you allow the $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ function, then that can be simplified as $$\left\lceil\frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{sgn}(x-T) + 1\right)\right\rceil$$
You can also completely replace the ceiling with $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{sgn}\left(\operatorname{sgn}(x-T) + \frac{1}{2}\right)+1\right)$$